# linker can't find crti.o and other object files

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker-errors

I'm using [this](https://github.com/apmorton/teensy-template/blob/master/Makefile) Makefile for a teensy project, and even though I have `crti.o`, `crtbegin.o` and `crt0.o` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and I have that directory in both `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I am still getting the following error upon running `make`:

```
[LD]    balloons-Parafoil.elf
/afs/.ir.stanford.edu/users/e/r/ericmark/Development/balloons-
Parafoil/tools/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-
none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/afs/.ir.stanford.edu/users/e/r/ericmark/Development/balloons-
Parafoil/tools/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-
none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/afs/.ir.stanford.edu/users/e/r/ericmark/Development/balloons-
Parafoil/tools/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-
none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [balloons-Parafoil.elf] Error 1
```

I should note that this error occurs both Ubuntu machines I have tried but not on a macOS machine that I am developing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C run-time files such as `crti.o` are highly machine-specific.  You cannot use the x86-64 version found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to create ARM binaries.  You need versions of these files for the variant of 32-bit ARM you want to target.  Looking at [the Canonical downloads page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), it does not look like current Ubuntu supports 32-bit ARM anymore, but you might be able install `libc6-dev:armel` after enabling the relevant Debian repositories.  It is also possible that the toolchain you use is not set up correctly.

Furthermore, if your ARM toolchain targets bare metal, glibc is of no use to you because glibc assumes that there is a running Linux kernel it can use.